# .NET cross-platform application works only when I build it on Windows, but not when I build it on Linux (Travis CI)

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform, travis-ci

My .NET 5 application [C#2J](https://github.com/softvis-research/csharp-to-json-converter) works in the Ubuntu subsystem when build on Windows with .NET version *16.7.0-preview-20310-07+ee1c9fd0c*.

`dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64`.

It does not work when build on Travis CI with .NET version *16.7.0-preview-20360-03+188921e2f*:

```
script:
  - dotnet-sdk.dotnet publish --runtime win-x64
  - dotnet-sdk.dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64
  - dotnet-sdk.dotnet publish --runtime osx-x64
  - *zipping*
```

The error I get when trying to run the app is:
`-bash: ./csharp-to-json-converter: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I read a couple of posts where people stated that this is probably an architecture mismatch but I don't think that is the case here as I am specifying the architecture in the publish command.

I made a diff between the version on Travis CI and my version locally and a couple of DLL's and the executable have indeed a different size. I had a look at [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10034) but it doesn't seem to be related.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I suspect that since .Net 5 is pre-release something went awry with Linux, i'd try to report it in .net github repos

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I created a ticket on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12977